# Hide and show Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I think i have done a right thing, I click the button and the paragraph doesn't appear. Can anyone help me why with my jQuery?

```
$('.open').on('click',function(event){
  $(this).nextAll('.ranch').toggle();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/dekovepuri/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: `$(this).parent().prev().toggle();` also add jQuery library in JSBIN

Comment: http://jsbin.com/famoqofeya/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: did you include j Query URL in you Page `  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`

Comment: @MohammadFareed ya i forgot to post it but still it doesnt work.

Comment: can you please tell me, what you need in your DEMO .? So that i can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no jquery plugin attached in your html. Please check console for error.

http://codepen.io/SESN/pen/WxxZOg

Here is your answer

```
 $('.open').on('click',function(){
 $(this).closest('.content').find('p.ranch').toggle();
 });
```

Comment: Thank you this is what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Lets make this simple

```
$('.open').on('click',function(){
   $('p.ranch').toggle();
});
```

hope this will work for you

Comment: if there many box like that .. if i click the button , all will effect, i want the effect 1 by 1 ,  if i use your suggestion 1 click all parent div will got the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do like this, it works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.open').on('click',function(){
 $('p.ranch').toggle();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

`.open` is nested in another element, `.nextAll()` looks for siblings. You'll have to go one level further backwards for that to work.

Here's how I'd find the parent `.content`, that's just me though:

```
$('.open').on('click', function(event) {
  $(this).closest('.content').find('.ranch').toggle();
});
```